# Sfdx Command is Behaving differently in different environments

Tags: salesforcedx, pipelines

I am trying to connect with a scratch org using the JWT token and when I am doing this from the local machine, it's working fine but failing when I run it from bitbucket pipeline.

I am able to connect with other orgs from pipeline but only one scratch org is behaving differently.

Anyone have an idea about it or should I provide some more information about it?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess with the current information is that your Bitbucket Pipelines might not have the right default dev org setup.  Set it either when initializing the scratch org (example provided in [JWT Based Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm))

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid 04580y4051234051 \
--jwtkeyfile /Users/jdoe/JWT/server.key --username jdoe@acdxgs0hub.org \
--setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias my-hub-org
```

...or setting before you create/connect to the scratch org:

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername=MyDevHubOrg
```